# and/or instead of if/else

Tags: python, if-statement, return-value

After working through some toy examples, I could see that it's possible to emulate the ternary operator of "c" `condition?value_if_true:value_if_false` in Python using `condition and value_if_true or value_if_false`.
I would like to know if it works in all cases and if it is better or worse than using `value_if_true if condition else value_if_false`.

Comment: Personally, the *precedence* of `.. if .. else ..` is clear. I'd at least have to think twice about an `.. and .. or ..`.

Comment: Why wasn't `condition and value_if_true or value_if_false` nuked from orbit in Python 3? I can't unsee this!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There's nothing wrong with the expression itself, only assuming that `X and Y or Z` will also evaluate to `Y` when `X` is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's strictly worse: the conditional expression was added to the language specifically to avoid the problem with using `... and ... or ...` incorrectly.

```
# 0 is falsy
>>> True and 0 or 5
5
>>> 0 if True else 5
0
```

PEP-308 references "FAQ 4.16" for other workarounds to the problems with `and/or`, though I can no longer track down what FAQ is being referred to, but it was eventually decided that a dedicated conditional expression was preferable.

For example, one could write

```
(True and [0] or [3])[0]
```

to ensure that the true-result is truthy, so that the false-result isn't returned. The false-result has to be adjusted as well so that regardless of what result is produced, it can be indexed to finally provide the intended result.